# Qual a análise morfossintática da frase: "A professora fez-me permanecer em sala."?

Tags: análise-morfossintática

Minha maior dúvida é o pronome "me" e sua função sintática. Mas para a resposta ficar completa podem sugerir a análise da frase completa.

Comment: "fez-me permanecer" me soa estranho. Não vejo o sentido de fazer-se no sentido de forçar https://dicionario.priberam.org/fazer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O pronome *me* é o sujeito da oração completiva. Sem o pronome teríamos algo como:

> A professora fez o João permanecer na sala.

O facto de encontrarmos o sujeito em acusativo leva a que esta construção seja chamada de *marcação de caso excepcional*. Se trocarmos o sujeito para a terceira pessoa podemos ver melhor que estamos perante o caso acusativo, e não dativo:

> A professora fê-lo permanecer na sala.

Na verdade, também podemos encontrar o sujeito em dativo, com verbos transitivos na completiva:

> A professora fez-lhe destruir o trabalho.

Mas esta construção é distinta da marcação de caso excepcional (é chamada de *fazer-infinitivo*). A frase que dás também encaixa nesta construção; neste caso a versão expandida seria:

> A professora fez permanecer o João na sala.

(O sujeito de permanecer ocorre agora após o verbo). Para o exemplo que dei antes seria:

> A professora fez destruir o trabalho ao João.

Neste caso, há quem defenda que não existem de facto duas orações, razão por que esta construção é chamada por vezes de *união de orações*. É uma construção mais limitada do que a *marcação de caso excepcional*; por exemplo não podes interpor *não*:

> A professora fez o João não permanecer na sala.
> *A professora fez não permanecer o João na sala.

Comment: Ótima explicação @Artefacto. Muito obrigado.